# Consequence of setup.py

Tags: ros, rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently setting up my first python based node. I have included a setup.py into my project and added the "catkin_python_setup()" macro in my CMakeLists.txt. I am now wondering, what the consequence of this is. Or, said differently, where can I see the result of adding setup.py and the macro?

I have checked the `$PYTHONPATH` and found that my python package can be found in `/path_to_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage`. Am I right that this folder has been generated by catkin when running setup.py? Are the modules of my package `mypackage` made available through  `/path_to_workspace/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage/__init__.py`?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295215/consequence-of-setup.py/) by [JayDe](https://answers.ros.org/users/29752/jayde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-06-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Correct! As long as you're using the devel space, catkin generates the file you mentioned via a cmake macro. When it is imported at runtime, it adds your source files (src/...) to the Python module path. As a consequence, you don't have to re-build your workspace unless you change setup.py itself.

---

Originally posted by [pgorczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/3055/pgorczak/) with karma: 446 on 2018-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2